# I am unable to retrieve values of selected checkboxes in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

can anybody tell me how should I retrieve values of selected checkboxes in angularjs. I will give you a brief scenario. I have an object called 'user' in which I have a list of permissions as a member of 'user'. Now in jsp I have several check boxes, what I want is when I check checkboxes the values of selected checkboxes should be mapped with permission list whoch is present in the 'user', How can I do that.?
I will show my permission checkboxes jsp code which is as follows

```
<div class="form-group required">
<label for="Permissions" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Permissions</label>
<div class="col-sm-6 Nopadding" data-ng-model="ctrl.user.permissionVoList.permissionId">
    <div class="checkbox"   data-ng-repeat="permissionVo in ctrl.permissionVoList" >
        <label data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right"
            data-html="true"
            title="<p align='left'>{{permissionVo.description}}</p>">
            <input type="checkbox" value={{permissionVo.permissionId}} /> {{permissionVo.permissionName}}
        </label>
    </div>

</div>
```

and 'user' object in the controller is as follows

```
 self.user={
                  userId:'1',
                  firstName:'Vishal',
                  middleName:'Vasant',
                  lastName:'Raut',
                  phoneNumber:'9898989898',
                  emailId:'vishal@gmail.com',
                  username:'vishal',
                  password:'111111',
                  notification:'no',
                  costPerHour:'1000',
                  roleVo:{roleId:''},
                  shiftVo:{shiftId:''},
                  permissionVoList:[{permissionId:''}]

            };
```

Comment: use ng-model for binding the value

Comment: I have used it, but the code seems to be not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
    angular.module('app',[]).controller('ctrlA',function(){
    var self = this;
self.selectedPermissions = [];
     self.user={
                      userId:'1',
                      firstName:'Vishal',
                      middleName:'Vasant',
                      lastName:'Raut',
                      phoneNumber:'9898989898',
                      emailId:'vishal@gmail.com',
                      username:'vishal',
                      password:'111111',
                      notification:'no',
                      costPerHour:'1000',
                      roleVo:{roleId:''},
                      shiftVo:{shiftId:''},
                      permissionVoList :[{permissionId:1,permissionName:"One"},{permissionId:2,permissionName:"Two"}]

                };
self.pushPermission = function(p){

  self.selectedPermissions.push(p);
}

    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrlA as ctrl">
    <div class="form-group required">
    <label for="Permissions">Permissions</label>
    <div>
     <label ng-repeat="permission in ctrl.user.permissionVoList">
        Label {{permission.permissionName}}
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="permission.isCheckd">
      </label>
     </div>
    </div>
    and 'user' object in the controller is as follows {{ctrl.user| json}}
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: its working around true or false but can you tell me how can I fetch "value" of the selected checkboxes, also permissionId is an int value not boolean. what can be done? @mohsin

Comment: what value you want ?? tell me the proper structure of permissionVoList

Comment: permissionVoList is the list of permissionVo object, permissionVo contains {permissionIdm permissionName etc.}, on UI user can select more than one permissions. so the values of checkboxes user selected on UI for permission will go in permissionId:something1, pemissionId:something2.. and so on... I need to wrap these permissionVo objects in one single list object i.e. permissionVoList

Comment: you can check for the property isCheckd whicheva is true is the permission that has been selected by user

Answer (score 0):

You can use pro-checklist model to retrieve data for the checkboxes. Visit the link [here](https://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/)